# Using webpack and babel with files from parent project directory

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have a project set up like this and I'm trying to require `file-a.js` from `file-b.js`.

```
project-name/
  node_modules/
  src/
    file-a.js
  tools/
    tool-name/
      node_modules/
      src/
        file-b.js
      webpack.config.js
      package.json
  package.json
```

My `webpack` 1.13.0 configuration was working until I added `babel-loader` 6.2.4 with `babel-preset-es2015` 6.6.0. Then I started getting error messages.

> ERROR in /home/dan/dev/dan/project-name/src/file-a.js
>   Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/home/dan/dev/dan/project-name/src"

Now I have a hunch that this is happening because it's looking for `babel-preset-es2015` in the upper `package.json`. I can make this error go away by installing it at that level, but then I get a similar message about the `babel` module not being there.

I've tried all sorts of things, symlinked the upper `src` directory into the inner project, used `resolve.root` and `resolve.alias` to try and manually resolve the folder without the nested path. Used `context` to set the project root as the outer folder, but it still picked up the wrong `node_modules`.

How can I force webpack to use the correct `node_modules` folder?

Answer (score 1):

By default webpack looks in `./node_modules`, `../node_modules`, and `../../node_modules`.

To force it to only use a specific directory, you can set an absolute path for the module `modulesDirectories` property in the `resolve` section:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
     modulesDirectories: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
  }
}
```

More details on `moduleDirectories` [in webpack's documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories)